# Updated Linux kernel broke amd drivers

Tags: boot, kernel, gpu, gpu-driver, amdgpu

Recently I upgraded my Linux kernel from 5.13 to the latest 5.15 on Ubuntu 22.04 but upon that happening the system won’t boot up. I know this has to do with the graphic drivers as the command: `lshw -c video` in the configuration tab shows `configuration: latency=0` which should show some driver but it doesn’t. Then when I run `ubuntu-drivers devices` it shows absolutely nothing. The drivers I had before where the Mesa drivers just to let you know. So I need a way to either switch the driver or install a new one.

System:

- CPU: intel core i7-3770
- GPU: Radeon rx560
- RAM: 12gb

Notes:

I can boot from a live usb, and just into the recovery mode menu, and lastly my system can’t connect to the internet in the terminal. So to install anything I need to connect to the internet.

Sorry if this is not all the information you need for a diagnostic.

Comment: Your timeline makes little sense to me, and I fear this provides clues you're missing. Ubuntu [21.10 used the 5.13 kernel and it reached EOL long ago](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/) with systems using it switching to 5.15 before that date (both 20.04 using HWE or 21.10 users when they upgraded to 22.04 which started with 5.15).  How do you define *recently*, as you're describing something from late June or early July if not before as I read it; is that *recent*?

Comment: @guiverc yah like I did it yesterday, and immediately after I upgraded the system would not boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. My Linux Kernel updated to 5.15.0-56 and now the system is not able to boot. I have a black screen.

I can go to the advanced option and boot older Kernel 5.15.0-53 and the system is able to boot.

The question is how to fix this problem without a new installation.

Thx for your help.

Comment: I guess I didn’t figure it to be so easy. I went into the advanced options and changed the version and it boots. Thanks

Comment: update to kernel 5.15.0-56 caused black screen as well using x.org driver and an NVIDIA card

Comment: Is there any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: I fix my problem by following the command line on this page.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu  

my fix was:
1 sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
2 sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
3 sudo shutdown -r now